# Regex capture all occurrences of a capture group(not with global modifier)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an xml database stuctured like this:

```
<mydatabase id="list01">
    <entryA author="none" desc="nothing">
        Text.
    </entryA>
    <entryB type="tag">
        More Text.
    </entryB>
    <entryA>
        Some text.
    </entryA>
</mydatabase>
```

From this database I'm trying to extract a list of entries:

```
class Entry{
   KeyValuePair<string, string>[] attributes; // the attributes key="value"
   string text; //The inner text
}
```

I am using regex to get the information(code + example: https://regex101.com/r/nI1hY8/2), but the tag and value in the match only appear once with the last captured matches.

Here's the regex:

```
<entry[A|B|C](?: (?'tag'(?:[a-z|A-Z])*?)="(?'value'.*?)")*?>\n\s*?(?'text'\S.*?)\n\s*?<\/entry[A|B|C]>
```

How can I get the whole list of tags and their values for each match using regex?

P.S. Yes I could add another capture group around the tags and process the text again with regex but that seems redundant since they've already been matched.

Edit: I do not want to use an XML parser.

Comment: If you are working with XML, you might want to consider using an actual XML parser as opposed to reading all of the content as text and using a regular expression.

Comment: Use an XML parser. Trying to use a regex here will only cause you headaches.

Comment: Also see how to create a [MCVE], i.e. add the information into the actual question not on an external site somewhere

Comment: It's an educative project I'm working and I want to parse all types of similarly structured databases. And it's neither hard nor impossible it's just this little thing which I could optimise that I'm curious. In short: no I don't want to use an XML parser.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I edited the question to include the regex. I didn't include it initially here since it seemed to me more readable and relevant on that site. I will keep this in mind in the future :)

Comment: *"I do not want to use an XML parser."*, why not? It's the right tool for the job. Sure you can stick a nail in the wall using your shoe, but it's a lot easier with a hammer. You are trying to stick a nail in with a lemon.

Comment: @MattBurland I don't want to because my goal is to integrate this into a text editor and be able to extract information from multiple types of databases. I used XML here mostly as an example. I want to also handle more weirdly-structured databases which obviously won't work when plugged into an XML parser... Right now I was exploring the regex method for parsing(out of curiosity, maybe I learnt something new) So NO, it's not the right tool for the job. I need a more flexible "shoe"(trying BNF now) not a rigid "hammer" :)

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do? What are you trying to capture from the input you give? And it looks like you are matching attributes and values not "tags". Please don't confuse things even more by using the wrong terminology. `<entryA>` is a *tag* `author` is an *attribute* and `none` is the *value* of that attribute. Are you trying to capture all the attributes in a single tag?

Comment: @MattBurland My bad for calling them tags instead of attributes. What I am actually trying to do is detect within a piece of structed text any type of list/database and extract the information accordingly by allowing the user(me, as it's a private project now) to input the format of the database/list and what info he wants extracted. A song list for **example** is something like `<tracknumber>.<artistname> - <songname> [ft. <colabartistname>][Remix][<year>|(<year>)]` and this would generate a table with the corresponding `<fields>`

Answer (score 1):

Use xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            //using unique keys
            Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = doc.Descendants("mydatabase").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => ((string)y).Trim())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            //when there are duplicate keys
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict2 = doc.Descendants("mydatabase").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => ((string)y).Trim())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());


        }
    }
}
```